# extracting data from function does not work R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

My problem is that I created a scoring function, which rates customers, depending on their RFM score and gives the output via print. However, I want to store the score in a new data.frame in order to create a ranking. 
I tried the return function and rbind as well with a data frame, that i created outside of the function. I read through many questions on this page and everyone suggests rbind or return as solutions. However, they do not work for me. 
I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Here my code, which I shortened due to its  repetitive behaviour:

```
d<-data.frame()
getscore<-function(data.frame){

score<-25
if(((actual.date-last.purch.date(data.frame)))*12<6)
  (
    score<-score+40
  )


score<-score+(amnt.purchases(data.frame)*6)

if((mean.last3purch(data.frame))<25)
  (
    score<-score+5
  )
return(score)
}
```

For better understanding: This is what i want.
That the code automatically assigns my scores to a new vector called score, which is then stored in a data frame, along with my other function(probability and the names for each customers) for reference purposes, i coded it manually.

```
     Customer<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
     Score<-c(123,312,312,4313,12,321,43)
     probability<-c(0.23,0.43,0.12,0.45,0.53,0.23,0.333)
     Ranking<-data.frame(Customer,Score,probability)
```

I tried the following : I created a new vector with the length of my total customers and assign the vector RFM to it. However, what happens when i execute the code is that the entire vector is filled with the score for the Customer. How would i tell the code to put the score in the accoring row ?

```
            RFM<-vector(length = length(Customers))
            df<-data.frame(RFM) 
            df$RFM <- getscore(Customers$A) print(df)
```

and when i tried the code sets the score from the first input again to zero

```
          RFM<-vector(length = length(Customers)) 
          df<-data.frame(RFM) 
          df$RFM <- getscore(Customers$A) 
          print(df) the code sets the score from the first input again to
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your approach. The final line of your function should be `return(score)`. Most likely, you will want to return a vector of all of the RFM scores from this function, then assign the output as a column to the data.frame. Something like `df$RFM <- get.score(inputObject)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the code still does not work.
I tried the following : 
I created a new vector with the length of my total customers and assign the vector RFM to it. However, what happens when i execute the code is that the entire vector is filled with the score for the Customer.
How would i tell the code to put the score in the accoring row ?
        RFM<-vector(length = length(Customers))
        df<-data.frame(RFM)
        df$RFM <- getscore(Customers$A)
        print(df)

Comment: and when i tried the following : 

        RFM<-vector(length = length(Customers))
        df<-data.frame(RFM)
        df$RFM <- getscore(Customers$A)
        print(df)
the code sets the score from the first input again to zero

Thanks in advance, Francisco

Comment: Consider incorporating your comments directly into your question.